# Hyphen needed in compound modifier with birthday cake/party?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

For example would it be a fifth-birthday cake or fifth birthday cake?

Comment: The single word ***fifth*** wouldn't be followed by a hyphen in such contexts. Look at over 7000 written instances of [***twenty-first birthday party***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22twenty-first-birthday+party%22) in Google Books.

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous without the hyphen whether or not it is correct. He ate his fifth birthday cake could mean he had already eaten four cakes and was on to the fifth. Perhaps  the numeral would make it a bit clearer: 5th birthday cake.

Comment: As above, I too think it would be ambiguous without the hyphen. "I'm planning for my twenty-first birthday party," would also be ambiguous,  but turning 21 is so momentous that few would misinterpret it. "He's excited about his second birthday party," would leave me in doubt.

Comment: I think FumbleFingers is wholly correct. Of course, Billy bunter forcing down five cakes in a row is possible, and won't context always make the meaning as obvious as whether I meant "line" or "argument"?